# Monotonicity of a differentiable positive function

Tags: calculus, monotone-functions

Suppose $y:[0, \infty)\to [0,\infty)$ is differentiable with $y(0)=0$ and such that for every $\delta>0$ we have that $y|_{0,\delta}\not \equiv 0$.

Does it follow that there exists $\varepsilon>0$ is strictly monotonic over $[0,\varepsilon)$?

This seems intuitively true, but I was not able to prove it.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer for the before edited question:**

Take $f(x)=|\sin x|$ and $\epsilon=\pi$, then $f(x)=\sin x\ne 0$ on $(0,\pi)$, and $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{+}}f(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{+}}\sin x=0$, but $f$ is not strictly monotonic on $(0,\pi)$?

**Answer for the edited question:**

Take $f(x)=x(\sin(1/x)+2)$ for $x>0$ and $f(0)=0$. Then $f(x)>0$ for $x>0$. And $f'(x)=\sin(1/x)+2-(1/x)\cos(1/x)$ for $x>0$. For large $n$, $\dfrac{1}{2n\pi+\dfrac{\pi}{4}}\leq x\leq\dfrac{1}{2n\pi}$, $f'(x)<0$ for such an $x$. For large $n$, $\dfrac{1}{2n\pi+\dfrac{3}{4}\pi}\leq x\leq\dfrac{1}{2n\pi+\pi}$, $f'(x)>0$ for such an $x$, so $f$ is not monotonic on each $(0,\epsilon)$.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Upvoted, but this is not what I meant. I'll restate the question.

Comment: For the new question, you may try $f(x)=x(\sin(1/x)+1)$ for $x\ne 0$ and $f(0)=0$.

Comment: Sorry, I think $x(\sin(1/x)+2)$ would be better.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no.

In fact for every positive  $\epsilon$ we can find a counter example.

Note that for a given $\epsilon \ge 0$ the function $$f(x)=sin( \frac {3\pi x}{4 \epsilon })$$ is a continuous function on $(0,\epsilon)$ and  $ \lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{+}}f(x)=0$ while the function is not monotonic on$(0,\epsilon)$ because it has a local maximum at $x= \frac {2\epsilon}{3}$.

Comment: I think this is no an answer for OP's question, because the function must be independent of $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: @user284331 Once the $\epsilon$ is given, the function will be independent of $  \epsilon$. I have actually proved a  stronger statement that for every  $\epsilon$ there exists a function which is continuous on$ ( 0,\epsilon ) $ and it is not monotonic.